# Structured logging to journald from within a docker container

Tags: docker, systemd, coreos

What is the best way to write structured logs to journald from within a docker container?

For example, I have an application that writes using [sd_journal_send](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man3/sd_journal_print.3.html)
Rather than change the app, I have tried passing through

-v /var/log/systemd/journal:/var/log/systemd/journal

It works on the my Ubuntu 16.04 desktop, but not on the CoreOS instances where the app runs (which use the Ubuntu 16.04 base image).  I don't quite understand why.  Perhaps there is a better way to send to the journal?

What limitations does the docker journald output logging option have?  It didn't appear it supported apps writing more than just the message field.

--

So I have found I need `-v /dev/log:/dev/log`

But there is also another problem in that there is no association to the service file that starts the docker container. Manually adding UNIT: servicename.service didn't solve it.  And so when looking at and shipping logs for the service, it's associated with the exe but not the container or service.  Whose encountered these problems and how have you solved them?

--
Ok let me expand this a bit.

A C program can write to the systemd journal like this:

```
#include <systemd/sd-journal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        sd_journal_send("MESSAGE=Hello World!",
                        "MESSAGE_ID=52fb62f99e2c49d89cfbf9d6de5e3555",
                        "PRIORITY=5",
                        "HOME=%s", getenv("HOME"),
                        "TERM=%s", getenv("TERM"),
                        "PAGE_SIZE=%li", sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE),
                        "N_CPUS=%li", sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN),
                        NULL);
        return 0;
}
```

This writes to the journal and adds custom fields like HOME, TERM, PAGE_SIZE etc.  When I use journalbeat to ship them to the ELK stack, those fields end up nicely in elasticsearch and I can search on them directly.

However, it seems that docker, simply takes the stdout of apps, and feeds it to the journald with only a few fields it adds itself. e.g. CONTAINER_ID.

When using programs like this inside a docker container and then running them from a service file it creates a slight problem.

1)  I have to pass through some directories and device files to get it to write with sd_journal_send.

2) if you start the container from a systemd .service file and expect to use journalctl -u servicename and see the messages, those log messages aren't seen because they went into the journal a different route and don't get associated with the service that ran them.

3) You can add some arbitary fields/tags using docker's journald logging driver, they are fixed, one time additions that will appear on every message sent and are unchanging.  They are not dynamic fields like I want from the C code above.

Essentially, the journald log driver is insuffient in my case.

Any suggestions on how both to link the service name so journalctl -u shows up the log messages from sd_journal_send? as that would fix it then.

--
I've found a solution.  I'll put the answer below in case others are interested in how I've solved it.

Comment: Will the Docker [journald logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/journald/) do what you want? In addition to the log message, it also stores other metadata like `CONTAINER_ID`, `CONTAINER_NAME`, `CONTAINER_TAG` etc.

Comment: I may not have made it clear.   I need to add my own fields and tie it all together within the same unit.  What's happening is basically `journalctl -u` sees it as another unit when the docker container app is started from systemd service file.  Docker is the issue.   I'll have to dive into the source and see what the sysyemd logging driver in docker it supports.  Might have to extend it.

Comment: Does this help https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332274/is-systemd-journald-a-syslog-implementation?

Comment: @TarunLalwani - nope.

Comment: How do i compile this on Ubuntu 16.04? I am getting `vagrant@vagrant:~/journald$ gcc test.c
/tmp/ccLHPQPH.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x8b): undefined reference to `sd_journal_send_with_location'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: `gcc test.c -l systemd`

Comment: I'm exploring another option.  It seems logstash can take json data in an arbitrary field (e.g. MESSAGE) and explode it into fields before submitting it into elasticsearch.  That would solve it for me.

Comment: @Matt, thanks for that command, figure out a solution to the original problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eventual solution turned out to be really simple.

I switched to writing my messages as pure json.  So journalctl -u now works and shows the MESSAGE field now containing json data.

I then used journalbeat to send that to logstash.

To logstash.conf I added:

```
filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
  }
}
```

What this does is it expands the json data from the message field into separate fields at the top level before sending them to elasticsearch.

Details about the json filter for logstash can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html)

Answer (score 5):

You need to mount the socket on which `journald` listens. In case of ubuntu it is `/run/systemd/journal/socket`. Map this insider you docker container and it would work fine

Figured that out using strace on your sample code

```
sendmsg(3, {msg_name(29)={sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/run/systemd/journal/socket"}, 
msg_iov(23)=[{"CODE_FILE=test.c", 16}, {"\n", 1}, {"CODE_LINE=13", 12}, {"\n", 1}, {"CODE_FUNC=main", 14}, {"\n", 1}, 
{"MESSAGE=Hello World!", 20}, {"\n", 1}, {"MESSAGE_ID=52fb62f99e2c49d89cfbf"..., 43}, {"\n", 1}, {"PRIORITY=5", 10}, {"\n", 1}, 
{"HOME=/home/vagrant", 18}, {"\n", 1}, {"TERM=xterm-256color", 19}, {"\n", 1}, {"PAGE_SIZE=4096", 14}, {"\n", 1}, 
{"N_CPUS=1", 8}, {"\n", 1}, {"SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=", 18}, {"a.out", 5}, {"\n", 1}], msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 208
```

And test it in ubuntu docker container using below

```
docker run -v /run/systemd/journal/socket:/run/systemd/journal/socket -v $PWD:/jd -it -w /jd ubuntu:16.04 ./a.out
```

And I get a entry in `journalctl -f` (on host)

```
Aug 15 21:40:33 vagrant a.out[11263]: Hello World!
```

Comment: Yes but it looses the association with the unit file when started as a systemd service.  And so, the journalbeat unit filter drops those messages.  Anyway, I've solved it by using the json filter in logstash see my answer.